# Celery: Routing tasks issue - only one worker consume all tasks from all queues

Tags: celery, celery-task

I've some tasks with manually configured routes and 3 workers which were configured to consume tasks from specific queue. But only one worker consuming all of the tasks and I've no idea how to fix this issue.

My `celeryconfig.py`

```py
    class CeleryConfig:
    enable_utc = True
    timezone = 'UTC'

    imports = ('events.tasks')
    broker_url = Config.BROKER_URL
    broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 10800}  # 3H

    worker_hijack_root_logger = False

    task_protocol = 2
    task_ignore_result = True
    task_publish_retry_policy = {'max_retries': 3, 'interval_start': 0, 'interval_step': 0.2, 'interval_max': 0.2}
    task_time_limit = 30  # sec
    task_soft_time_limit = 15  # sec

    task_default_queue = 'low'
    task_default_exchange = 'low'
    task_default_routing_key = 'low'

    task_queues = (
        Queue('daily', Exchange('daily'), routing_key='daily'),
        Queue('high', Exchange('high'), routing_key='high'),
        Queue('normal', Exchange('normal'), routing_key='normal'),
        Queue('low', Exchange('low'), routing_key='low'),
        Queue('service', Exchange('service'), routing_key='service'),
        Queue('award', Exchange('award'), routing_key='award'),
    )

    task_route = {
        # -- SCHEDULE QUEUE --
        base_path.format(task='refresh_rank'): {'queue': 'daily'}
        # -- HIGH QUEUE --
        base_path.format(task='execute_order'): {'queue': 'high'},
        # -- NORMAL QUEUE --
        base_path.format(task='calculate_cost'): {'queue': 'normal'},
        # -- SERVICE QUEUE --
        base_path.format(task='send_pin'): {'queue': 'service'},
        # -- LOW QUEUE
        base_path.format(task='invite_to_tournament'): {'queue': 'low'},
        # -- AWARD QUEUE
        base_path.format(task='get_lesson_award'): {'queue': 'award'},
        # -- TEST TASK

    worker_concurrency = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1  #
    worker_max_tasks_per_child = 1
    worker_max_memory_per_child = 90000  # 90MB

    beat_max_loop_interval = 60 * 5  # 5 min
```

I run workers in a docker, part of my `stack.yml`

```
    version: "3.7"

    services:

      worker_high:
        command: celery worker -l debug -A runcelery.celery -Q high -n worker.high@%h

      worker_normal:
        command: celery worker -l debug -A runcelery.celery -Q normal,award,service,low -n worker.normal@%h

      worker_schedule:
        command: celery worker -l debug -A runcelery.celery -Q daily -n worker.schedule@%h

      beat:
        command: celery beat -l debug -A runcelery.celery

      flower:
        command: flower -l debug -A runcelery.celery --port=5555 

      broker:
        image: redis:5.0-alpine
```

I thought that my config is right and run command correct too, but docker logs and flower shown that only worker.normal consume all tasks.

I [image: flower screen]

**Update**

Here is part of task.py:

```
def refresh_rank_in_tournaments():
    logger.debug(f'Start task refresh_rank_in_tournaments')
    return AnalyticBackgroundManager.refresh_tournaments_rank()
```

base_path is shortcut for full task path:
`base_path = 'events.tasks.{task}'`

`execute_order` task code:

```py
    @celery.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=5)
    def execute_order(self, private_id, **kwargs):
        try:
            return OrderBackgroundManager.execute_order(private_id, **kwargs)
        except IEXException as exc:
            raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

This task will call in a view as `tasks.execute_order.delay(id)`

Comment: can you please add 'tasks.py'  @kotmsk

Comment: What is `base_path`? And add `tasks.py`

Comment: I've updated topic message.

Answer (score 0):

Your *worker.normal* is subscribed to the *normal,award,service,low* queues. Furthermore, the *low* queue is the default one, so every task that does not have explicitly set queue will be executed on *worker.normal*.

Comment: I've specified queues and routes in `celeryconfig.py`

Comment: ok, but task `execute_order` execute on worker.normal in spite of it has explicitly set the queue `high`.

Comment: Your Flower screenshot does not say what tasks were executed, so I could not possibly know what is going on there... Also you did not give us the code for `execute_order`, and how you call it...

Comment: Tasks were executed well, the number 195 is amount of executed tasks, no doubt. I've updated my initial post and added some code.

Comment: You have explicitly set the queues for your workers and only worker.normal is subsribed to the `low` queue which is set to the the default. So, when you run `tasks.send_pin.delay(pin, id)` it will go to the default queue (which in your setup is `low`).

Comment: Well, `send_pin` task was bad examlpe. The `execute_order` task has explicitly set the queue `high` and `worker.high` must service `high` queue and consume tasks from them, but `execute_order` also consumed by `worker.normal`.